# Centering Bootstrap row content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to to horizontally center the content in div class "row". I've tried using justify-content-center, other variations.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Text</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
            </p>
            <p>
                Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="img-responsive" srcset="icon.png 1x, iconRetina.png 2x">                
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="img-responsive" srcset="downloadOnAppStore.png 1x, downloadOnAppStoreRetina.png 2x">                
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I can see how the answers are centering the content, but it's not quite what I mean. I want width of the content size to align to the center of the page, no matter how wide the page is.

How it is now:
[image]

I'd like to transform it to something like this:
[image]

The problem seems to be that columns take up 50% of the row's width.

Comment: That seems to have no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that `justify-content-center` is the best option:

```css
.portfolio-item {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
 <div class="container">

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Text</a>
                </h3>
                <p>
                 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                </p>
                <p>
                 Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img-responsive" srcset="icon.png 1x, iconRetina.png 2x">                
                </a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img class="img-responsive" srcset="downloadOnAppStore.png 1x, downloadOnAppStoreRetina.png 2x">                
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please see my edits in my question. I may update it with an image to visualize it.

Comment: @ChewieTheChorkie check it now

Comment: That works with your bootstrap version. It looks like it seems to be the version of bootstrap that I have.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap has total 12 grid. you have use 8 grid. use this class  (offset-md-2) it will push 2 grid from left side. then your content will center

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
 <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item offset-md-2">
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Text</a>
                </h3>
                <p>
                 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                </p>
                <p>
                 Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Text</a>
                </h3>
                <p>
                 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
                </p>
                <p>
                 Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

[image]

Comment: see now i have upload images

Comment: Has no effect on centering the content like the image I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I got the code working below using your code. The "justify-content-center" works for me on row. Also, I added "text-center" to your "col", just in case you want those centered as well - but you can remove those two if you want them right aligned.

I ran into this problem when I didn't have bootstrap updated. Maybe that's also your problem.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item text-center">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
        </h3>
        <p>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
        </p>
        <p>
            Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item text-center">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="img-responsive" srcset="icon.png 1x, iconRetina.png 2x">                
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img class="img-responsive" srcset="downloadOnAppStore.png 1x, downloadOnAppStoreRetina.png 2x">                
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to give `justify-content-center`.

```css
.bg-color{
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center bg-color">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
      <h3>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
      </h3>
      <p>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
      </p>
      <p>
        Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
      </p>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
      <h3>
        <a href="#">Text</a>
      </h3>
      <p>
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
      </p>
      <p>
        Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
      </p>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain how do you want..? because center thing is working fine.

Comment: Please see my edits in my question. I may update it with an image to visualize it.

Comment: That still aligns both columns to the left

Comment: I would still like two columns

Comment: I know but I am just explaining you that it's center not left align. I think you are doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of answers here, but the most straightforward way would be to make use of Boostrap's `justify-content-center`.

Alternatively, a pure CSS approach would be to make use of the `justify-content` CSS property, and set it to `center`. This is because Bootstrap's [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) is based on [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). You may assign the 'justify-content' property to the element with the `row` class. This is basically similar to what`justify-content-center` class does.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row" style="justify-content:center">
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Text</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.
            </p>
            <p>
                Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="img-responsive" srcset="icon.png 1x, iconRetina.png 2x">                
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img class="img-responsive" srcset="downloadOnAppStore.png 1x, downloadOnAppStoreRetina.png 2x">                
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```